# All content not visible with div height 100%

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am loading my div content from a php file (15 items) via Jquery. All the content is there once the height of the div is 500px but once I want it to be 100% some of the data is not there. It loads more on scroll when is 500px in height but does not scroll once it is 100%. How may I solve this please? Thank you.

```
#list {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   left:0%;
   width: 350px;
   padding-left: 80px;
   height: 1000%;
   border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px -5px #888888;
   -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px -5px #888888;
   -webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px -5px #888888;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: There's only code for 1 tag out of 5, being CSS.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: `height: 1000%;`?? This is not `100%`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even when correct answers are given

Comment: Yeah, seen this movie quite a few times; more than I'd like to @UncaughtTypeError it's always the same ending.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a bad trope. We prefer the ones where the "good guys" get the karma they deserve when the conflict is resolved.

Comment: Try `height: 100%; position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is caused by the following CSS (I changed the `height:1000%` that's in your CSS to `height:100%` as your question describes):

```
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
height: 100%;
```

- `position: fixed` tells the browser to keep that element in the same place, regardless of how much the browser window is scrolled.
- `top: 50px` tells the browser to position the element 50 pixels from the top of the browser window.
- `height: 100%` tells the browser to make the height of the element the same height as the browser window (regardless of the `top` position).

Because `position:fixed` means that the element doesn't move when the page is scrolled, you're always going to have 50 pixels at the bottom of the element that are always going to be hidden, because the element position is fixed and won't change when you scroll.

If you need your element to always be 50 pixels from the top of the screen and 0 pixels from the bottom of the screen (regardless of scrolling), don't specify a `height` at all, and instead do:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
bottom: 0px;
```